# How add transition for translateX with one timing function and transition for translateY with another timing function simultaneously?

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-transitions

I would add transition for translateX with one timing function and transition for translateY with another timing function simultaneously

code:

```
transform: translateX(200px) translateY(200px);
transition: translateX 1s linear, translateY 1s cubic-bezier(.66,-0.68,.96,.56);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pure CSS, but even better than `CSS Transition` or `jQuery animation`!
You can use [[ `VELOCITY.JS` ]](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity)

See what you want [[ HERE ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FmoDp)

Good Luck